# PHP not getting $_POST from ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I'm trying to post data to the same page.

I can see that the post from the ajax is working correctly but the `$_POST` in my `index.php` isn't finding the post after form submission.

```
<form method="post" id="classic_login" action="">
    <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username" class="classic_field" id="user_field" />
    <input type="text" name="pass" placeholder="Password"  class="classic_field" id="pass_field" />
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="classic_button" id="login_button" />
    <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" class="classic_button" id="register_button" />
</form>
```

and I've tried both `print_r($_POST)` and `isset` both don't change after submission

```
print_r($_POST);
if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass']))
   echo "works";
```

printing formdata after a test submission i get: user=testuser&pass=testpass

```
$("#classic_login").submit(function(event) {
    var formdata    =   $(this).serialize();
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax
    ({
        url: "",
        type: 'POST',
        data: formdata,
        //success: function(response) { alert(response); },
        error:  function() { alert("fail"); }
    });

});
```

Comment: why you commented your success method?

Comment: As far as My understanding is concerned, If you want to post the form to the same php file,you can simply use action="your.php". Then why do you use ajax?

Comment: @Abdul no reason, was just testing. Forgot to uncomment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use `document.URL` to make a request on the same page. Then in PHP, include an `exit;` after the request:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
    exit; // this is important!
}

?>

<form method="post" id="classic_login" action="">
    <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username" class="classic_field" id="user_field" />
    <input type="text" name="pass" placeholder="Password"  class="classic_field" id="pass_field" />
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="classic_button" id="login_button" />
    <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" class="classic_button" id="register_button" />
</form> 

<!-- this is no brainer, of course you need to load the library -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#classic_login").submit(function(event) {
    var formdata  = $(this).serialize();
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: document.URL, // you can use this
        type: 'POST',
        data: formdata,
        success: function(response) { 
            alert(response); 
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/h2UY4u)

Comment: Forgot to mention, the js is external it's path to the index is: js/main.js

Comment: @joe sure, this answer's straightforward anyways, there's no need to big modifications, kindly try this one

Comment: Ok tried and still nothing, the print_r never executes or changes from "Array()"

Comment: @joe aside from the fact that there is already a working demo, i don't know to help more than that. its already on the same page. acutally you can just copy this answer straight up. here is the demo http://codepad.viper-7.com/h2UY4u

Comment: my response when alerted is very different to yours, mine is printing the entire html out in the alert: http://i.imgur.com/J5GMQLC.png  could that have anything to do with it? Like i said my JS is external and not in index.php

Comment: @joe regardless of where the js is located, it should be fine. just make sure that this is in your JS `url: document.URL`. and in PHP. put this in the end of file. `exit;` after the request. just emulate what i did in the PHP of the answer. if you do not have an exit. it will get the whole document

Comment: @joe and remember to put the php part above the html. and use a catching block for that ajax request. like mine above `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){`. all inside your processes which you will need to be returned on the success block of ajax should be done in there, and then put an `exit;` at the end

Comment: Putting the php above the html and using the response from success: properly worked :)

Comment: @joe yeah i forgot to state that above said answer. sure man im glad this helped